# How to convert an Integer param in JAXB?

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb

I am creating a SOAP service using JAX-WS and JAXB. There is a count param. How can I using a costomize DataTypeConvert to convert it? I want to convert an Integer(not a POJO) param object by my costomisze DataTypeConvert. Because if the SOAP message contain "count" tag, this value will be set to 0, but if the SOAP message without "count" tag, this value will be set to null. I want make set this param to null in both two scenarios. If the Integer field in a POJO, I can use @XmlJavaTypeAdapter to convert it. But @XmlJavaTypeAdapter can't use on an Integer param which driectly in the method.

```
     @WebMethod
     public Team getTeamByCondition(@WebParam(name = "Name") String name,
        @WebParam(name = "Condition") String condition,
        @WebParam(name = "Count") Integer count) {
     }
```

If there anyone can tell me how JAX-WS convert params?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper class for your count with JAXB.

```
@XmlType
class Count {
    @XmlValue
    Integer count;
}
```

An alternative...
If you want to use a wrapper class take a look at [XmlAdapter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html). They have pretty good samples there. Basically you annotate your Integer with @XmlJavaTypeAdapter. The annotation should point to an adapter you create. You still need to create a wrapper class like the above but your adapter can map any Integer you have defined to this wrapper class.

Comment: Is there any way I can apply my own DataTyepConvert? I don't want to use wrapper classes for every simple data type.